# How to detect enter input in Python?

Tags: python, if-statement, ascii, enter, ord

I'm making a hangman game,

I'm just about completely done but the one thing that doesn't work is if the user, for input, presses the enter key, it just says they win.

So I've been trying to find ways to detect the enter input, and then from there just `continue` back to the while loop.

I've tried doing

```
if guess == ord(13):
   print("Please enter a letter.")
   continue
```

and

```
if guess == '\r'
    print("Please enter a letter.")
    continue
```

neither really work,

and for some reason, it goes into my for loop, iterating through thinking that it is inside my answer word even though my answer word is .. a word and not any enter keys and essentially filling the list and making it win the game, so have to find a way to detect the enter key.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide a minimal example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example This will help us help you. From the code you posted we cannot see where `guess` is coming from. And there is a lot of superfluous context in your question, such as you are writing a hangman game and that somewhere in your code there is a while loop and so on. This is all not necessary to solve your problem to detect an Enter input.

Comment: Please provide a more complete code, it's complicated to resolve this without all the informations.

Comment: If the user presses Enter immediatly, it means the input is empty. So basically `if guess == ""` should do the job

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If we want to get an input and want to verify that the user did not just simply enter nothing, we could create a `while` loop that calls for input until the input differs from the empty string:

```
guess = ""
while guess != "":
    guess = input("Please Enter a letter!")
```

We can put this anywhere in your code and afterwards go on and use `guess` as we need.

Comment: What's wrong with this answer that you gave it downvote? Just curious.

Answer (score 1):

When someone hits the enter key for input, the input string is blank. So you should just check for an empty string to detect the Enter key:

```
guess = input("Enter guess:")
if not guess:
    #this means someone just hit the enter key
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using regex:

```
import re

if not re.match('[a-zA-Z]', guess):
    print("Please enter a letter.")
    continue
```

The added benefit of reversing your logic here is that you catch anything that's not an uppercase or lowercase letter.